# app unfortunately stopped form codenameone with paypal integration

Tags: android, paypal, codenameone

Written the below code in native interface implemented class:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.R;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.*;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.codename1.impl.android.IntentResultListener; 
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity;
//import com.codename1.impl.android.LifecycleListener;
//import com.codename1.impl.android.OnInitListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;


public class MyNativeImpl{
 // private static final String TAG = "paymentdemoblog";
/**
 * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION to move real money.
 * 
 * - Set to PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX to use your test credentials
 * from https://developer.paypal.com
 * 
 * - Set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK to kick the tires
 * without communicating to PayPal's servers.
 */
// private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT =
// PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox
// environments.
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "Aeqc2X1rBIEUtDNqsaRNr0h1neFo9QnNmfgmpA3D32uSLaHpGJu9NV1KfMnFmy7O-_hV47I7ST0SXDW2";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
        .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
        .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
        // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
        .merchantName("Hipster Store")
        .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(
                Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
        .merchantUserAgreementUri(
                Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));

PayPalPayment thingToBuy;
private static Activity activity() {
    return com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
} 


public String payPalTest() {

  AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {           
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity(), PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        activity().startService(intent);
     }
  });
     AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
    thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("10"), "USD",
    "HeadSet", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity(),
    PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
    activity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

     AndroidNativeUtil.startActivityForResult(intent, new IntentResultListener(){ 
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(confirm.toString());
                    System.out.println(confirm.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(activity(), "Order placed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            System.out
                    .println("An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PayPalAuthorization auth = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
            if (auth != null) {
                try {

                    String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                    Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                    sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                    Toast.makeText(activity(),
                            "Future Payment code received from PayPal",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("FuturePaymentExample",
                            "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            Log.i("FuturePaymentExample",
                    "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
} 
    }); 
     }
     });

//    thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("10"), "USD",
//                      "HeadSet", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
//              
//              Intent intent = new Intent(activity(),PaymentActivity.class);
//
//              intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
//                                activity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

//Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
//intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.javatpoint.com"));  
//activity().startActivity(intent); 

    return "test";
}
private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

}
public void onDestroy() {


}
public boolean isSupported() {
    return false;
}

}
```

call from main class:

```
 MyNative my = (MyNative)NativeLookup.create(MyNative.class);
        if(my!= null){
          String aa =my.payPalTest();
          System.out.println("result::" + aa);
            System.out.println("paypalInt" + my.toString());
        }
```

The code build succesfully but when I have tried to access it from android mobile,it gives error:

Unfortunately  has stopped.How to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have an uncaught exception, connect your device with cable and open android ddms to see the trace and log